# DataGridView make Cells unselectable

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi I have c# datagridview and everytime when I hit TAB i got focused cell in my datagridview. Does anyone know how to deny focusing cells in datagridview? I need to mark only row not cells.
Thank you

Comment: You want to prevent getting focus only when tab key pressed or by clicking with mouse also?

Comment: When I click on my row I select only row not cell, so only by tab key pressed, thank you

Comment: Did you set `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;` ? If yes it won't show only cell as selected, it will always show whole row as selected.

Comment: Have a look on this picture: http://rygol.cz/screen.png

Comment: I have SelectionMode set on FullRowSelect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem. You're taking about focus rectangle. You can prevent it by subscribing `RowPrePaint` event and remove the focus *PaintPart*.

```
private void dgv_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.PaintParts &= ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus;
}
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/331438/2530848)